# React native styles not combining

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to pass the `fontSize` as a style property to my component. The `fontSize` doesnt change any ideas how I can pass the `fontSize` as a prop to overwrite the default size?

```
<Homemenu navigation={navigation} style={styles.homeMenu} />

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
....
  homeMenu: {
    fontSize: 16,
  },
});
```

In my homeMenu:

```
      render() {
            let {style, navigation} = this.props;
            let fontSize = style && style.fontSize ? style.fontSize : null;

            return (
              <View style={styles.container}>
                  <View style={[styles.menuItem, fontSize]}>
                    ....
                  </View>
                const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    ...
        menuItem: {
        fontSize: 26
  },

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are unnecessary bother for falsy values in `style` prop. I don't see any issue of why it shouldn't work. Code looks good to me.

```js
<Homemenu navigation={navigation} style={styles.homeMenu} />

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  ...
  homeMenu: {
    fontSize: 16,
  },
});

render() {
  let { style, navigation } = this.props;

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={[styles.menuItem, style]}>
        ....
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  ...
  menuItem: {
    fontSize: 26
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it correct, the only change you need to make in 
`<View style={[styles.menuItem, fontSize]}>`
is you should update the existing style object

```
style={{...styles.menuItem, fontSize}}
```

Basically it should be iterable, so that your second value can overrride the first one. And we should not enclose it with square brackets and we should use curly braces, since it is object.

Comment: I think thats not required because the code gets compiled to `<View style={[{ fontSize: 26 }, { fontSize: 16 }]}>`, which should work perfectly.

Comment: actually it should be like style={{ fontSize: 26, fontSize: 16 }}, is not it? and not with those square brackets?  we are passing objects and not array if I am not wrong.

Comment: No both are correct. You can pass an array of styles as well, mostly useful when you have multiple styles to be passed.

Comment: I prepared a demo, check this out https://codesandbox.io/s/react-native-styles-gallery-ie9k0?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: yes, I agree with you, we can use both ways in react-native, spreaded operator is supported in both react and react-native and we can use them according to our convenience.